# How to override the default Startup UI?

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to change the new Preset Menu UI to display the selected Preset name in the Properties Header like it appeared in the previous versions (2.79-).  I know how to do it successfully, but I have to change the original Blender UI startup script, which I know we should not do. I only need to change 3 variable assignments in a Class method.  If I change the original script, I will have to make the same changes every time I download a new version.  How do I implement the changes so they are not overridden by new versions?

Here is the script that needs changing - its in /scripts/startup/bl_ui/utils.py

My changes are in the draw_panel_header method.

```
def draw_panel_header(cls, layout):
layout.emboss = 'NORMAL'
layout.popover(
    panel=cls.__name__,
    icon='NONE',
    text=cls.bl_label,
)
```

```
from bpy.types import Menu
# Panel mix-in class (don't register).
class PresetPanel:  
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'  
    bl_region_type = 'HEADER'  
    bl_label = "Presets"  
    path_menu = Menu.path_menu

    @classmethod
    def draw_panel_header(cls, layout):
        layout.emboss = 'NONE'
        layout.popover(
            panel=cls.__name__,
            icon='PRESET',
            text="",
        )

    @classmethod
    def draw_menu(cls, layout, text=None):
        if text is None:
            text = cls.bl_label

        layout.popover(
            panel=cls.__name__,
            icon='PRESET',
            text=text,
        )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.emboss = 'PULLDOWN_MENU'
        layout.operator_context = 'EXEC_DEFAULT'

        Menu.draw_preset(self, context)
```

Comment: Please fix the code markdown in question. Either select the code and ctrl-k or {} button, or indent all one right before pasting.  It is not the job of others to do this for you every time.

Comment: Sorry, but this thing has a mind of its own.  I try editing the formatting but it just gets mangled by the web page.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks